# Ingress factions: only appears to be one group in my city

Tags: ingress

I'm trying to sign up for Ingress and choose a faction. I like the idea of playing for the underdog to try and balance things out, but there literally appears to be only one faction in my city. The Ingress map shows a score of 818 for one team and a score of 0 for the other. If I join the 0 scoring team, will I just be bored because I can't do anything? If I join the team everyone else is on, will I bored? I don't understand the game enough yet.

Comment: That's because everyone is mesmerized by Pokemon GO right now. Ingress was pretty cool in it's day, but I think it's time has passed, unfortunately.

Comment: @TimS. Also note that it's summer and a lot of the Ingress players are on vacation. PoGo is getting all the attention in media right now unlike Ingress (I've been playing since 2012). We'll see in a couple of months time what gives.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about the "Regional Scores" section in the "Intel" section of the Ingress app or the "Regional Score" line on the Intel map, that score just displays the current status of the current running cycle. If you're living in a sparsely populated region that score won't change too much in the future but if you're not then it could be just a momentarily score. Watch it for further developments.

In any case your movements surely would be recognized by players of neighboring regions and if you insist on playing the game they surely will contact you because Ingress players always need players from neighboring regions for bigger fields and are in the lookout for persistent newcomers.

Ingress is still being consistently played by both its core players and the newcomers. Please don't hesitate to join this growing community.

Answer (score 1):

When you join Ingress, your main focus is to level up quickly.

If there aren't many neutral portals around your place, and you choose to be underdog, you may have a difficult start - where you can only hack enemy portals but can't really capture anything or create links and fields.

If there are, I'd choose the underdog path, it's much more fun.

Use the [intel map](https://www.ingress.com/intel) to decide.

Comment: I made this choice in the town I live in. There was only one resistance player who owned the whole town. He is level 9. I decided it would be much more fun to go against him so I am slowly gaining levels (currently level 6) and getting strong enough to take down his portals and then send him messages which is fun! I managed to get some big boosts in AP by claiming portals in other towns when I was out for the day, that definitely helps!

Comment: Hacking enemy portals also gives points so even low level players can get to a higher level. Trying to find weak portals and eliminating them or fields also provides you with much needed AP. Asking for someone to help out from out of town also can give you a boost and they might enjoy doing missions or getting unique captures. Also, deploying on top of other's resonators gives AP.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have a lot more fun in the enemy area.

That's were I make AP and I like to blow things up.

However, it might be difficult for beginners since before level 6 attacking portals is mostly useless.

But, once you're 6+, it's quite fun to go to a green (I'm blue) area destroy it all, capture, link, field!

Comment: This doesn't really address his question, but rather  seems to address the opposite of what is being asked.